# How can i save state of JCheckBox

Tags: java, checkbox, save, checkboxlist, jcheckbox

I have a JDialog with JCheckboxs and a JButton "ok"
I want to select all the JCheckBoxs that I need and press the button "OK" to save the state of JCheckBoxs. And in other class I have a program that I press a button and send a Msg in JOptionPane with the JcheckBox I selected

Please, help me.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isSelected()` for example you have two `JCheckBox` so you can get result of them like so :

```
boolean check1 = checkbox1.isSelected();
boolean check12 = checkbox2.isSelected();
```

If you want to save the state of your checkbox, i suggest to use a `Map` that take the `String` as name of your JCheckBox and `Boolean` as the state like this :

```
Map<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<>();
result.put(checkbox1.getName(), checkbox1.isSelected());
result.put(checkbox2.getName(), checkbox2.isSelected());
```